# C# SoundPlayer - should be static or instance based?

Tags: c#, wpf, static, instance-variables, soundplayer

I am using SoundPlayer class in C# (WPF), to play the same .5s audio over and over (on key press). Every time user presses custom on-screen keyboard buttons, sound plays.

```
static SoundPlayer soundPlayer = null;
try
{
  soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\media\click.wav");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Logger.LogException(e);
}
// later on (usage)    
try
{
  soundPlayer?.Play();
}
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on if I should keep this SoundPlayer obj as static or if I should change to instance based? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone provide some guidance on if I should keep this SoundPlayer obj as static or if I should change to instance based?

It depends on where and how the `SoundPlayer` is intended to be used in your application. If you will/can always use same instance of the `SoundPlayer` without modifying it in any way, you could define it as a static and readonly field in your class:

```
private static readonly SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\media\click.wav");
```

Then there will only be one instance created regardless of the number of runtime instances of your class. The `Play()` method will play the .wav file using a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think this makes little difference, because either way it only needs to be instantiated only once - since you are playing the same file.

Declare a class member of type `SoundPlayer`, and instantiate it using initializer.

```
static SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\media\click.wav");
```

or

```
SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\media\click.wav");
```

and whenever you need to play the sound,  you don't need to perform null-check against it, just call

```
soundPlayer.Play();
```

For resource disposal, call `Dispose` method on the instance if you no longer use it, for example, when the window is closed.

```
soundPlayer.Dispose();
```

Comment: Both answers helped greatly, in not needing to perform null check (and mark as readonly from mm8. Ty both

Comment: The accepted answer is a better one since it introduces the _readonly_ keyword to enforce that the constructor will not be called more than once.